# Wordpress previous and next links on CPT Page called from Archive

Tags: wordpress, archive

I have a CPT and 3 custom taxonomies. For each of the taxonomies there exist archive pages with items for the taxonomy term ordered by title.

The item page has prevoius/next-Links in the footer, but these are linked to the previous/next item of this CPT in publish date.

How can I substitute this with a link to the previous/next item in the archive, as the visitor would expect?

A first idea is to transport the loop content from the archive page and looking up the neighbor items?

Comment: e.g. CPT for fruit, entries (last entered first):


    * banana
    * apple
    * grape
    * cherry
    * kiwi

Any taxonmy page lists the items in title sorted order by 'pre_get_posts'-filter in theme:

    * apple
    * banana
    * cherry
    * grape
    * kiwi`

When the "cherry"-page is called from the archive, the previous link should link to "banana", the next link to "grape"

The actual approach is to fill a $_SESSION variable with id,title and link of the posts during the loop on archive page and retrieving the neighbor values by post id on item page

Answer (score 0):

You need to add this code to your single-myposttype.

```
/* Fist get the posts from specific taxonomy */
$postByTaxonomy = get_posts(array(
  'post_type' => 'post', // fruit
  'numberposts' => -1,
  //'order'          => 'ASC', // you can add to order by name
  //'orderby'        => 'title', // you can add to order by name
  'tax_query' => array(
    array(
      'taxonomy' => 'fruit-category', // category of Fruit CPT
      'field' => 'slug',
      'terms' => 'fruit-category-1', // This is the one you check from editor page
    )
  )
)); 

/* Store the IDs in array from get_posts above */
$theIDs = array();
foreach ($postByTaxonomy as $pbt) {
  $theIDs[] += $pbt->ID;
}
/* print_r($theIDs) = Array ( [0] => 3696 [1] => 3697 [2] => 128 [3] => 4515 [4] => 4516 [5] => 4514 ) */


/* Now we will use a php function array_search() for us to get the current post and we can set the previous and next IDs */
$current = array_search( get_the_ID(), $theIDs); /* here you need to get the id of the post get_the_ID() or $post->ID */
$prevID = $theIDs[$current-1];
$nextID = $theIDs[$current+1];

/* DISPLAY - Now that we have the IDs of the prev/next post you can use them to your template in your case the permalink */
<a href="<?php echo get_permalink($prevID); ?>"> Previous</a>
<a href="<?php echo get_permalink($nextID); ?>"> Next</a>
```

Comment: Unfortunately it's not that simple, I think.

Comment: My template is single-myposttype and is used for all the pages, so its not for a specific taxonomy. The theme uses the_post_navigation() which gets the previous/next depending on the publishing date and not the sort order.

What I try to do:

- on the archive page of any of the taxonomies the user gets to the item page by clicking the item title or image

- on the item page the previous/next links to the previous/next item in the same sort order the archive page is sorted

Comment: Hard to explain what I mean, I guess. My problem ist **not** on the **archive page**, which perfectly meets my needs. My problem is getting the correct previous/next item link and title on the **item page**, when called from the archive page. I try to make a new entry to explain better.

Comment: see new comment in question

Comment: I have updated my answer to your question on the comment. 

For us to get the correct prev/next links we need to create a new query with the correct sort. 

Then, Store the the IDs in array() so we can use the PHP function array_search() for us to get the prev/next IDs. 

After retrieving the IDs, you can do pretty much do everything from there. you can get the permalink, title, featured image etc.